# ElectronJs: What does curly braces '{}' mean in package json

Tags: json, npm, electron, package.json

I was going through some electron package.json examples where I found some `interpolations` like given below:

```
"updater": {
    "urls": {
      "darwin": "{{& SQUIRREL_UPDATES_URL }}/update/%CHANNEL%/darwin?version=%CURRENT_VERSION%",
      "win32": "{{& SQUIRREL_UPDATES_URL }}/update/%CHANNEL%/win32",
      "linux": "{{& SQUIRREL_UPDATES_URL }}/update/%CHANNEL%/linux"
    }
  }

  "piwik": {
    "serverUrl": "{{& PIWIK_SERVER_URL }}"
  },
  "sentry": {
    "dsn": "{{& SENTRY_DSN_PRIVATE }}"
  }
```

I do not really know the following:

1. what does this {{}} mean in json
2. where does these variable exist
3. what does `&` mean in `{{}}` `"{{& SENTRY_DSN_PRIVATE }}"`

If anyone can explain then it would be really kind. Many thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about [Whatsie](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie) and it's [package.json](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/src/package.json).

If you take a look at one of the Gulp tasks located in the file [tasks/compile.coffee](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/tasks/compile.coffee), you'll be able to see the lines (in CoffeeScript):

```
# Move package.json
gulp.task 'compile:' + dist + ':package', ['clean:build:' + dist], ->
  gulp.src './src/package.json'
    .pipe mustache process.env
    .pipe gulp.dest dir
```

Here the actual [package.json](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/src/package.json) is being passed to a [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) template engine - it receives a template as a first argument ([package.json](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/src/package.json) here acts like a template)  and a data to be inserted in the template as a second argument - `process.env`.

As [package.json](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/src/package.json) acts like a template for [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), you can use [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) syntax in it.
Curly braces `{{}}` are the part of it, they are used as placeholders which will be replaced by the actual data, when templates are being compiled. In the [mustache docs](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) you can also find a line:

> You can also use & to unescape a variable: {{& name}}

So `{{& name}}` is to prevent values from being escaped. Otherwise, if you don't use `&` and values for output have some dangerous characters , they will be replaced by more secure ones (originally to prevent XSS in templates), as a result it will transform initial value, which is not always what you want. In this case author wants to preserve original value.

Going back to `process.env` - it is an object which gives access to [environment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) in Node.JS. There is a file in repository [.env-example](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/.env-example) with an example of env variables developer has to set in order to have the application work differently in different environments (for example on local machine or CI server). Names of some of the variables in this file are the ones that are used in a [package.json](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/blob/master/src/package.json) as template placeholders - I guess author of the app uses all of this to simplify a build process for different environments.